# Shopping Cost Total in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to work on a simple program in Python which will ask me how much each item for a shopping list will cost.

I wanted the program to repeat and ask me each time the next price for which to add to a grand total which works.

The list can not exceed ten items and when the tenth item is entered I wish the program to stop and display the total cost of all the items, additionally I want it so if '-1' is entered, the program will do the same behaviour as if it was the tenth item.

I'm a bit stuck on working out how to not add '-1' to the total and which variables will be necessary in order to store the running cost and count the items have been entered. Also unsure on my syntax for the IF Statement.

```
enter = int(input("How much is the item: "))
enter2 = int(input("Next item: "))
enter3 = int(input("Next item: "))
enter4 = int(input("Next item: "))
enter5 = int(input("Next item: "))
enter6 = int(input("Next item: "))
enter7 = int(input("Next item: "))
enter8 = int(input("Next item: "))
enter9 = int(input("Next item: "))
enter10 = int(input("Next item: "))
total = enter + enter1 + enter2 + enter3 + enter4 + enter5 + enter6 + enter7 + enter8 + enter9 + enter10
print("Total price is", total)

if input == -1 or > 10:
   print("Total price is", total)
```

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this with loops. find one approach here. https://repl.it/@venky18/DampTangibleSuperuser

Answer (score 1):

Do your input validation before continuing with the next input

```
i=0
enter = []
while i < 10:
   item = int(input("Next item: "))
   if item == -1:
       break
   enter.append(item)
print("Total is: " + str(sum(enter)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
enter = int(input("How much is the item: "))
if enter != -1:enter2 = int(input("Next item: "))
if enter2 != -1:enter3 = int(input("Next item: "))
if enter3 != -1:enter4 = int(input("Next item: "))
if enter4 != -1:enter5 = int(input("Next item: "))
if enter5 != -1:enter6 = int(input("Next item: "))
if enter6 != -1:enter7 = int(input("Next item: "))
if enter7 != -1:enter8 = int(input("Next item: "))
if enter8 != -1:enter9 = int(input("Next item: "))
if enter9 != -1:enter10 = int(input("Next item: "))
total = enter + enter1 + enter2 + enter3 + enter4 + enter5 + enter6 + enter7 + enter8 + enter9 + enter10
print("Total price is", total)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error with the if-statement.

`if input == -1 or > 10:`

Should be like this:

`if input == -1 or input > 10:`

Answer (score 0):

Use loops, https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/

```
total = 0
for i in range(10)
    itemPrice = int(input("Next item: "))
    if (itemPirce = -1):
        break
    total = total + itemPrice
print("Total price is", total)
```

for i in range (10) - iterates 10 times, like the following:
i =0, i=1, ..,.., i=8, i=9

That is 10 times in total.

If you want to break out from the loop, use "break" command.
Here break will be activated only if the price is -1.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't entirely sure how to best address your issue -- specifically, is this python 2 or 3? I took some guesses and tried to support both. I also added a bit of flavor. Hope you don't mind!

```py
from __future__ import print_function

from random import randint
from time import sleep

INVALID_INPUT = -2
GIMME_A_SUBTOTAL = -1
ALL_DONE = -3

def safe_int(v):
    try:
        return int(v)
    except ValueError:
        return INVALID_INPUT


def prompt_for_number(label):
    return safe_int(input("{0}\n> ".format(label)))


def make_label():
    yield "How much is the item?"
    while True:
        yield "How much is the next item?"


def cart_status(cart, final=False):
    if len(cart) == 0:
        return "Your cart is empty"
    return "Your {0}total is {1}".format(("" if final else "sub"), sum(cart))


def simulate_calculation():
    max_itr = randint(4, 9)
    for i in range(max_itr):
        print("Calculating Items{0}{1}\r".format("."*(i%4), "   "), end="", flush=True)
        sleep(.25)
    print()


def barcode_scanner():
    stop_early = []
    cart_items = []
    queries = {
        INVALID_INPUT: lambda : "Invalid input. Please supply a Natural Number.",
        GIMME_A_SUBTOTAL: lambda : cart_status(cart_items),
        ALL_DONE: lambda : stop_early.append(True),
    }
    label_maker = make_label()

    while len(cart_items) < 10 and len(stop_early) == 0:
        v = prompt_for_number(next(label_maker))
        msg = queries.get(v, lambda: "Beep".format(cart_items.append(v)))()
        print(msg)

    simulate_calculation()
    print(cart_status(cart_items, True))
    print("Thank you for your patronage!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        barcode_scanner()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nCancelling the transcation")
```

A quick note: If you're using python 3, you can instead opt to use formatted strings, and replace lines like this:
`"{0}\n>".format(label)` 
with this:
`f"{label}\n>"`